# What's the R function used to find unique and distinct value in a column?

Tags: r

What's the R function used to find unique and distinct value in a column?

if there is a column names as below:

```
Names
A,A
B,A
C
C,V
V,C
Z,X
```

how can i get output as A,B,C,V,Z,X (unique ad distinct)
i know unique() would do row-wise computation and i need it for entire column and row precisely.
Anyone able to help me?

Comment: `result <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$Name, ',')))`

Comment: @RonakShah - Thanks for your response, But i'm getting below error while executing it >>   Error in strsplit(netflix$country, ",") : non-character argument

Comment: `df$Name <- as.character(df$Name)`

Comment: got it thanks...cont <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(netflix$country),",")))